# What is this kind of variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables

I am trying to decipher a javascript and I found this kind of variable.
Could someone please tell me how it works? Before judging me for asking such a stupid question instead of googling it I'd like to point out that googling something you don't even know of is quite hard. I tried javascript variable types but no luck. :)

```
if (! this.sh_languages) {
  this.sh_languages = {};
}
sh_languages['tcl'] = [
  [
    [
      /#/g,
      'sh_comment',
      1
    ],
    [
      /\b[+-]?(?:(?:0x[A-Fa-f0-9]+)|(?:(?:[\d]*\.)?[\d]+(?:[eE][+-]?[\d]+)?))u?(?:(?:int(?:8|16|32|64))|L)?\b/g,
      'sh_number',
      -1
    ],
    [
      /"/g,
      'sh_string',
      2
    ],
    [
      /'/g,
      'sh_string',
      3
    ],
    [
      /~|!|%|\^|\*|\(|\)|-|\+|=|\[|\]|\\|:|;|,|\.|\/|\?|&|<|>|\|/g,
      'sh_symbol',
      -1
    ],
    [
      /\{|\}/g,
      'sh_cbracket',
      -1
    ],
    [
      /\b(?:proc|global|upvar|if|then|else|elseif|for|foreach|break|continue|while|set|eval|case|in|switch|default|exit|error|proc|return|uplevel|loop|for_array_keys|for_recursive_glob|for_file|unwind_protect|expr|catch|namespace|rename|variable|method|itcl_class|public|protected|append|binary|format|re_syntax|regexp|regsub|scan|string|subst|concat|join|lappend|lindex|list|llength|lrange|lreplace|lsearch|lset|lsort|split|expr|incr|close|eof|fblocked|fconfigure|fcopy|file|fileevent|flush|gets|open|puts|read|seek|socket|tell|load|loadTk|package|pgk::create|pgk_mkIndex|source|bgerror|history|info|interp|memory|unknown|enconding|http|msgcat|cd|clock|exec|exit|glob|pid|pwd|time|dde|registry|resource)\b/g,
      'sh_keyword',
      -1
    ],
    [
      /\$[A-Za-z0-9_]+/g,
      'sh_variable',
      -1
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      /$/g,
      null,
      -2
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      /"/g,
      'sh_string',
      -2
    ],
    [
      /\\./g,
      'sh_specialchar',
      -1
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      /'/g,
      'sh_string',
      -2
    ],
    [
      /\\./g,
      'sh_specialchar',
      -1
    ]
  ]
];
```

At first I thought it was a dictionary, but it did not seem that way.

Chrome throws this error when trying to declare it:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Comment: That is invalid syntax.

Comment: I think you'll need to paste the whole code for us to be able to say certainly, but it just looks like a bunch of nested arrays with a regex in the middle.

Comment: You mean this: http://code.google.com/p/wikitcl/source/browse/trunk/wubwikit/docroot/scripts/sh_tcl.js?spec=svn1576&r=1576

Comment: Are you asking about JavaScript's object literal notation, which inspired the data exchange format JSON?

Comment: We can offer you more help if you provided the code you are working on

Comment: @RoyMJ That looks like it. Or at least similar (probably same idea), though I'm not seeing the octothorpe in that code.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard: Exactly as you said. It contains the regex inside a couple of arrays. But not sure whats the real purpose?

Comment: `var sh_languages['tcl'] = ..` is invalid. It must be a plain identifier that follows `var`, not an expression (even that of an Reference Sepcification Type).

Comment: @PatrikJ: Unless you modify the question to ask a question that requires any proper help from the guys here, most probably this will be closed..

Comment: Added the whole code in case someone was curious. But I've got the answer I was looking for below. Wasn't looking for the whole solution, just what to call the ['xxx'] part. And apparently it was called property. Case closed.

Comment: Of course, thanks for all the help! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message points out, it isn't any kind of variable. It is a syntax error.

Let's break it down:

`var sh_languages` declares a variable called `sh_languages`.

`sh_languages['tcl']` accesses a property named `tcl` of an object stored in a variable named `sh_languages`.

You can't declare a variable and access a property of an object in that variable in the same statement.

`[` starts an array literal.

`[[` starts an array literal, then starts another array literal and puts the second array in the first index of the first array.

`[[[` and a third array as the first index of the second array. It's turtles all the way down.

`/#/g` is a regular expression literal. It matches `#` characters and has the global flag. The regular expression would be the first index of the third array.

`,` the comma separates the first index from the second index.

Answer (score 3):

`var sh_languages['tcl'] = ..` is invalid. It must be a plain identifier that follows `var`, not an expression (even that of an Reference Sepcification Type).

A correction, keeping in line with the form used, would be:

```
var sh_languages = {};
sh_languages['tcl'] = ..;
```

Or alternatively, the key could be written as part of the object literal itself:

```
var sh_languages = {
   tcl: ..
};
```

The `..` stuff, as whatever is in the original, is an expression formed by various literals (array, string, regular expression, etc.) In this case that is some form of tree (nested arrays) with a prescribed format; the usage of the data therein depends on the semantic meaning.